# Visual Studio (2012) changing a dll to export classes and variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, export

I created a VC++ Win32 Console Application and ticked DLL but forgot to also tic "Export Variables". Later I noticed that classes, variables etc.  in there didn't get exported to the calling application (which was using [DllImport...]).

Sure, I can create a new DLL and tic the "Export" option, but is there also a way to do that in hindsight?

Answer (score 1):

It all comes down to declaring exported names `__declspec(dllexport)`.

The "Export" checkbox simply generates an extra `.h` file that defines, among other things like:

```
#ifdef MYPROJECT_EXPORTS
#define MYPROJECT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYPROJECT_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

So that in your code you can later write:

```
MYPROJECT_API void MyExportedFunction();
```

You can also reuse this declaration in the DLL as well as the client code that uses your DLL (note that `MYPROJECT_EXPORTS` is automatically defined regardless of the "Exports" checkbox).

You can't have the `MYPROJECT_API` generated later but you can easily make one manually and/or declare your exported functions `__declspec(dllexport)` with other means.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change that later on, too. Just create a new DLL project where you export stuff and compare the project files. You could also tweak things in the project setup UI, but it might be more difficult.